# python: attributes on a generator object

Tags: python

Is it possible to create an attribute on a generator object?

Here's a very simple example:

```
def filter(x):
    for line in myContent:
        if line == x:
            yield x
```

Now say I have a lot of these filter generator objects floating around... maybe some of them are anonymous... I want to go back later and interrogate them for what they are filtering for. Is there a way I can a) interrogate the generator object for the value of x or b) set an attribute with the value of x that I can later interrogate?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, generator objects (the results returned from calling a generator function) do not support adding arbitrary attributes. You can work around it to some extent by using an external dict indexed by the generator objects, since such objects *are* usable as keys into a dict. So where you'd *like* to do, say:

```
a = filter(23)
b = filter(45)
...
a.foo = 67
...
x = random.choice([a,b])
if hasattr(x, 'foo'): munge(x.foo)
```

you may instead do:

```
foos = dict()
a = filter(23)
b = filter(45)
...
foos[a] = 67
...
x = random.choice([a,b])
if x in foos: munge(foos[x])
```

For anything fancier, use a class instead of a generator (one or more of the class's methods can be generators, after all).

Answer (score 19):

Yes.

```
class Filter( object ):
    def __init__( self, content ):
        self.content = content
    def __call__( self, someParam ):
        self.someParam = someParam
        for line in self.content:
            if line == someParam:
                yield line
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to interrogate them for debugging purposes, then the following function will help:

```
import inspect

def inspect_generator(g):
    sourcecode = open(g.gi_code.co_filename).readlines()
    gline = g.gi_code.co_firstlineno
    generator_code = inspect.getblock(sourcecode[gline-1:])

    output = "Generator %r from %r\n" % (g.gi_code.co_name, g.gi_code.co_filename)
    output += "".join("%4s: %s" % (idx+gline, line) for idx, line in enumerate(generator_code))

    output += "Local variables:\n"
    output += "".join("%s = %r\n" % (key,value) for key,value in g.gi_frame.f_locals.items())

    return output

print inspect_generator(filter(6))
"""Output:
Generator 'filter' from 'generator_introspection.py'
   1: def filter(x):
   2:     for line in myContent:
   3:         if line == x:
   4:             yield x
Local variables:
x = 6
"""
```

If you want to interrogate them to implement functionality then classes implementing the iterator protocol are probably a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You can't set arbitrary attributes on generators.

As S. Lott points out, you can have a object that *looks* like a generator, and *acts* like a generator.  And if it looks like a duck, and acts like a duck, you've got yourself the very definition of duck typing, right there.

It won't support generator attributes like `gi_frame` without the appropriate proxy methods, however.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about the problem, there *is* a way of having generators carry around a set of attributes.  It's a little crazy--I'd strongly recommend Alex Martelli's suggestion instead of this--but it might be useful in some situations.

```
my_content = ['cat', 'dog days', 'catfish', 'dog', 'catalog']

def filter(x):
    _query = 'I\'m looking for %r' % x

    def _filter():
        query = yield None
        for line in my_content:
            while query:
                query = yield _query

            if line.startswith(x):
                query = yield line

        while query:
            query = yield _query

    _f = _filter()
    _f.next()
    return _f

for d in filter('dog'):
    print 'Found %s' % d

cats = filter('cat')
for c in cats:
    looking = cats.send(True)
    print 'Found %s (filter %r)' % (c, looking)
```

If you want to ask the generator what it's filtering on, just call `send` with a value that evaluates to true.  Of course, this code is probably too clever by half.  Use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very belated answer, but...

Instead of storing and later reading some additional attribute, your code could later just inspect the generator's variable(s), using:

filter.gi_frame.f_locals

I guess Ants Aasma hinted at that.

Comment: I tried your suggestion to inspect the generator's variables. It works so far as `StopIteration` has not yet been reached. After that, `gi_frame` becomes `None`.

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote a decorator to do this here:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577057-generator-attributes/