# Python: how to calculate the sum of a list without creating the whole list first?

Tags: python, list, sum, yield

Usually we have to (1) declare a list (2) calculate a sum of this list using `sum()`

But now I wish to specify a list start with 1 and interval 4, 100 elements, like this:

```
[1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,37,…]
```

I don’t want to envolve mathematical formula, so

> (1) How to get the sum without even declaring this list?
>
> (2) How to quickly get sum from 101st element to 200th element of this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to get a counter and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the required number of elements (you can iterate these instances but they don't create a list!):

```
>>> from  itertools import count, islice
>>> sum(islice(count(1, step=4), 100))  # get the first 100 elements and sum them
19900
```

The `islice` also supports start/stop:

```
>>> sum(islice(count(1, step=4), 101, 200))  # 101st element to 200th
59499
```

Answer (score 3):

The built-in class [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) does does exactly what you want in Python 3. In Python 2, use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange). instead. For example:

```
for i in range(1, 401, 4): ...
```

The `range` object does not contain a full list. It records only the start, end and step size. The iterator will also record the current position.

It is important to use `xrange` in Python 2 because the range function will return the entire list, which is exactly the opposite of what you want.

```
a = range(1, 401, 4)
sum(a)
```

will compute the sum you want and allow you to reuse `a` afterwards.

**A note on the number 401**

The end of a range is exclusive. There are a couple of common formulas to get the correct number of elements in the range. `start + count * step` is the one I have chosen here because it is the easiest. It is also the largest number that will give `count` rather than `count + 1` elements to the range. `start + (count - 1) * step + 1` is the formula for the smallest number that will give you `count` elements. Since you want 100 elements, an end value of 398, 399, or 400 would give you the same result as 401.

Comment: It's not really accurate to describe Python 3's `range` object as a generator. It's a sequence object, not an iterator. In addition to reusing it, you can do stuff like `len(range(...))` and `range(...)[index_or_slice]` and it works. That's not possible with generators.

Comment: @Blckknght. It absolutely is if the generator defines the appropriate methods. But you are right, range is not a generator since you can't call next on it.

Comment: You can't define methods on a generator object. You create one by calling a generator function (a function with `yield` expressions in it), or using a generator expression. You can write your own iterator class, but that's not the same thing as a generator. And if you want to have `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods, you probably want your type to be a sequence (like `range` is) and not be an iterator.

Comment: @Blckknght What if you define a class with a `__call__` method that does `yield`?

Comment: Just so we're clear, I'm about to fix my answer because I basically agree with you. Just super slow on mobile

Comment: @Blckknght I removed the cruft about generators. However, just to be pedantic looks like you were technically correct, the best kind of correct: http://stackoverflow.com/a/956667/2988730

Comment: If you have a `__call__` method that is a generator, then the instances of the class will behave like generator functions. The methods you define still won't be used by the generator objects you get from calling an instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generators with `sum` to avoid creating a list at first:

```
result = sum(x for x in range(1, 401, 4))
```

As @Mad Physicist mentioned in the comment, you don't even need the `x for x` part:

```
result = sum(range(1, 401, 4))
```

Comment: That's not a list comprehension and passing in range by itself is fine.

Comment: No problem. See the comment I made for the other answer. `x for x in... ` is almost never necessary.

Comment: It's technically called a generator expression, not a comprehension: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/292/generators#t=201609020956268959493

Answer (score 2):

You can write a generator:

```
def ir(start=1, end=400, step=4):
    while True:
        yield start
        start+=step
        if start>=end: break
```

Or, if you want a specific number of elements:

```
def ir(start=1, n=100, step=4):
    cnt=0
    while True:
        yield start
        cnt+=1
        start+=step
        if cnt>=n: break
```

And then sum that:

```
 >>> sum(ir())
 19900
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because you can include a whole lot more in a custom function, like skip ever 20th or simulate the [Gregorian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)